# Texts on aero-engine structures

Tags: aircraft-design, turbofan, engine-design, aircraft-structures

I have been scouring the web for resources on aero-engine structures and structural design (preferably civil turbofans) but unfortunately it seems like they are hard to come by. I would like dedicated texts on stuff like engine loads, what the major load-bearing components are, engine-airframe integration, what modelling techniques are used (from simple analytical/empirical models in prelim design all the way to perhaps advanced thermomechanical FEA), what the design considerations are etc.

I figured that most of this info might not be in the public domain because of trade secrets and such, but I was wondering if anyone could still point me in the right direction. I've been trying to piece together my understanding through reading some of the AIAA and ASME papers and even some of the OEM patents but would also like more comprehensive texts like the ones in https://www.ae.msstate.edu/tupas/SA2/Reference.html for general aircraft structures.

Comment: Try the [NASA Technical Reports Server](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/). You can access the archive of NASA reports though it may take some searching to find what you're looking for.